# Readln with TIdCmdTcpClient

Tags: indy

I have a TIdCmdTCPClient which receives commands teminated in LF from a tcp server (written in C) into commandhandlers and accordingly updates a UI using TIdNotify. All is fine if it was not that somtimes I need to talk to the server in the traditional way using writeln and readln. If I try to do it there are problems such as the UI freezes, subsequent commands arrive later etc.

IS there a specific way to make work the pair writeln-readln just fine with TIdCmdTCPClient as they work with TIdTCPClient?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more informmation about the protocol you are implementing.  You can certainly issue additional `WriteLn()` and `ReadLn()` calls while you are inside of a command handler event, as long as that is what the server is expecting you to do. But if you need to call `ReadLn()` out-of-band then you are going to conflict with `TIdCmdTCPClient`'s internal reading.

Comment: It is a propietary simple text protocol of the form 'command param_1 param_2 param_n<LF>' with LF always at the end of reading or writing. In fact what I need sometimes is out-of-band communication, and in fact this conflicts with the internal reading of TIdCmdTCPClient. If I set CommandHandlers[x].Enabled to False, issue wiretln and readln, and then enbale it, does this will still conflict with the internal reading of TIdCmdTCPClient?

Comment: If your client receives a command, then sends a response, then receives an ack/whatever, that is fine to do inside the command handler. But disabling individual command handlers does not stop `TIdCmdTCPClient` from continuing to do its internal reading, it will just pass any received data to its `DoReplyUnknownCommand()` method instead (which is empty in TIdCmdTCPClient` but can be overriden in a descendant class).

Comment: If the client needs to send its own outbound command and get a response back, you have to handle that carefully. I would suggest using `TIdTCPClient` instead so you can do your own reading and writing on your own scheduling. You can still use `TIdCommandHandlers` for parsing inbound commands, just instantiate and fill it manually in your code.

Comment: My calient is a game application which sends some commands and receives a lot of commands to update UI accordingly. Using TIdCmdTCPClient made it very handy and esay to deal with that. However, sometimes i need and immediate response. If I understand correctly TIdCommandHandlers may be used with TIdTCPClient. This may be a fine solution to benefit from the two approaches. Can you detail it more, and if with some example better, thnx..